# Question about MCAR, MAR and MNAR

Tags: missing-data, mcar, mnar

I have 3 datasets. Each of the three datasets “data1.csv”, “data2.csv”, “data3.csv” is about the same sample of 654. (I imported the datasets in R studio.)

subjects: youths, aged 3 to 19
with the following variables:

- age, positive integer (years);
- fev (forced expiratory volume), continuous (liters);
- ht (height), continuous (centimeters);
- sex, nominal (Female=0, Male=1);
- smoke, nominal (Nonsmoker=0, Smoker=1).

Question: identify the missingness mechanism (MCAR, MAR, MNAR) of “fev” for each dataset....
How to do that? thanks Chiara

Answer (score 0):

I used a function written by Stemmler (2020) to perform Little's MCAR test for my data. It will give you a p-value and tell you if your data is missing completely at random. The URL below includes the function and has more information.

https://stats-bayes.com/post/2020/08/14/r-function-for-little-s-test-for-data-missing-completely-at-random/

Apologies: adding an edit. The function posted above can be used in R. This test can also be done in SPSS but I am not sure how.

Hope this helps!